# How to solve a reCaptcha manually in the Browser

Tags: python, automation, recaptcha, captcha, solver

Is there a way where you can solve a recaptcha manually by just having the link where the captcha appears and the sitekey (captcha solving services are not a opportunity for me because they are to slow for what i wanna use this for)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to use it for? Captchas are generally put in place to *prevent* people from performing certain operations (like creating new users) extremely quickly.

Comment: Automated Checkouts